# Adding a title (header) to every table row

Tags: html, html-table, row, title

I'm trying to create a header for each table row that spans over all columns and acts like a block element. A table row separator, if you like, but with text.
I tried using the TH within the rows, but it behaves like a normal cell. I want it to behave like a block element spanning across all cells in a row and not counting as a cell for the thead cells.
Is there any way to accomplish that?

Because the table is sortable I don't want to add another tr with colspan="2" to every row.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
    <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>This th should span the two cols as a header</th>
      <td>coll 1 data</td>
      <td>coll 2 data</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>This th should span the two cols as a header</th>
      <td>coll 1 data</td>
      <td>coll 2 data</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: How is the table being sorted? i.e. is the sorting script examining the td cell contents, or can you set the values for sorting on the table row using a `data` attribute?

Comment: @girlwithglasses you're right I completely missed that sentence!

Comment: I'm using the Tablesorter 2.0 jQuery plugin.
But apart from that, it's just not possible to add a sort of heading to a table row in any way?